# Are there any methods to isolate zone.js from other code?

Tags: angular, zone.js

There is an issue: There is a client code and I should use an angular based widget on the page. So angular uses zone.js and this one affects all global async methods, but it brakes the client scripts. The question is: Can I start the zone in an isolate scope maybe, or start client code in some wrapper which isolates their code from the influence of the zone.js ?

Comment: I discovered a lot and It looks like there isn't any way to resolve this issue. Guys from angular said what it is normal and zone should be transparent for the other code. But for us, it is a critical moment so we went out to another framework.

Comment: could you explain why you want to run without zone? in angular, by default you are in ngZone, you can runOutsideAngular to exit ngZone, but you still under root zone.